# Avoid registered naming with a specific technology

Tags: bluetooth

In order to avoid possible conflicts with Bluetooth SIG, I would like to know if there's an easy way to refer to this technology without naming it, such as BT, or BLE, so that the user understands it.

Comment: There are no laws against writing a factually true statement which has the word "Bluetooth" in it. If you're writing documentation, the best way to refer to Bluetooth is to use the word "Bluetooth." The only time you have to be careful is if there's a chance your writing might lead someone to mistakenly think that your product is made by or endorsed by Bluetooth SIG.

Comment: OK, so could I add a modal in a mobile app indicating "do you want to turn on the bluetooth?"

Comment: I'm guessing that would be fine. An even safer option would be "Do you want to turn on communication with Bluetooth devices?"

Comment: @TannerSwett  OK, thank you very much!